# Random Number Generation in C# errors out

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, numbers

So i am trying to generate a *random number* and if the number is `3` or `8` i what something to happen , it this case to *add* `1` to one of the 2 integers

keep in mind i really am only going off a book in C# and some knowledge in VB

```
    int Number1 = 0;
    int Number12 = 0;
    string text;
    string text2;

    Exexs:

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int month = rnd.Next(1, 10);

    if (month = 8)
    {
        Number1++;
    }
    else if (month = 3)
    {
        Number12++;
    }

    if (Number1 = 1)
    {
        text = "*";
    }

    goto Exexs;
```

Comment: First of:: **never ever** use `goto`. It makes your code hard to read and to debug. Apart from this you **should** read some book about C#, or at least some tutorials.

Comment: you are missing '==', in the if condition . For example if(month = 8) needs to be ifImonth==8)

Comment: Do not recreate `Random` - `Random rnd = new Random();` - do it *once* and then use it

Comment: although it's obvious but why don't you mention exact error of your code?

Comment: Please tell us what the error is.

Comment: HimBromBeere - i have gotten kick out of lectures for using GoTo how i know why thank you 
 Anu Viswan - i will give it a shot thanks

Comment: How would you know what the results are from running this code? It outputs nothing and runs forever... an endless loop!

Comment: Your question is not answerable at all to us. It seems to have many errors, of which you provided none. However as of the comments to Pitrs answer you seem to have a specific problem which we can´t guess here at all. Thus this questions lacks relevant information, voting to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Too many errors are in your code; it seems, the implementation should be something like this:

```
int Number1 = 0;
int Number12 = 0;
// Do not forget to initialize the varaiables:
string text = "";
string text2 = "";

// Create (and initialize by system tomer) Random once, use many
Random rnd = new Random();

// Do not use goto, but loops (they are more readable: we have an infinite loop here)
while (true) {
  int month = rnd.Next(1, 10);

  // (month = 8) is an assignment, not comparison which is (month == 8)
  // Let's use C/C++ language trick: comparing in reversed order: 
  // (8 == month) and you can easily find out such errors
  if (8 == month)
    Number1++;
  else if (3 == month)
    Number12++;

  if (1 == Number1) {
    text = "*";

    // you want to leave the infinite loop (your current code never stops)
    break; 
  }
}

// Let's inspect the outcome
Console.Write($"Number1 = {Number1}; Number12 = {Number12} Text = {text}");
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# in order to compare you need to use double **=**
So, instead of :

```
if (month = 8)
```

type:

```
if (month == 8)
```

Comment: Thanks to all you guys i fixed it , and the errors were something about int not being a bool

Comment: @Kernel Making this question not answerable as it lacks every relevant information.